# AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'tell'

Tags: python, image, smtplib, imghdr

I am using `email.message` and `smtplib` to send emails using python. When an image is sent as an attachment, it raises this error:

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'tell'
```

Here is the code for the image attachment:

```
if filetype.lower() in ['jpg','jpeg','png','gif']:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        file_data = file.read()
        image_type = imghdr.what(file_data)
    
    actual_filename = filename.split('/')[-1]
    msg.add_attachment(file_data, maintype='image', subtype=image_type, filename=actual_filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather doing

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
    file_data = file.read()
    image_type = imghdr.what(file_data)
```

you might do

```
image_type = imghdr.what(filename)
with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
    file_data = file.read()
```

as [`imghdr.what(file, h=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html#imghdr.what) does

> Tests the image data contained in the file named by file, and returns
> a string describing the image type. If optional h is provided, the
> file argument is ignored and h is assumed to contain the byte stream
> to test.